# ng-show vs ng-if in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

`ng-if` and `ng-show` seems to be work similar.

```
<img src="spinner.gif" ng-if="showSpinner">


<img src="spinner.gif" ng-show="showSpinner">
```

Is there any difference between them? any performance impact? 
How to decide where to use them properly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ngIf differs from ngShow and ngHide in that ngIf completely removes and recreates the element in the DOM rather than changing its visibility via the display css property. A common case when this difference is significant is when using css selectors that rely on an element's position within the DOM, such as the :first-child or :last-child pseudo-classes.

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf

Comment: @elclanrs: the weird thing is, sometimes I don't even remember googling for a piece of info. It just appears on my screen. :)